# How to read warehouse name from a different table in snowflake task creation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a snowflake task where the current active warehouse will be assigned to the task by making a query to another snowflake table. I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task_name
warehouse = {select query for different table}
schedule = '1 minute'
As
some SQL;
```

Could someone help me to understand if and how it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its ok to set SQL variable then one approach as below -
Use/replace what-ever query in below to get warehouse name

```
set my_wh=(select current_warehouse());
+----------------------------------+
| status                           |
|----------------------------------|
| Statement executed successfully. |
+----------------------------------+

select $my_wh;
+------------+
| $MY_WH     |
|------------|
| COMPUTE_WH |
+------------+

CREATE TASK t1
  warehouse = $my_wh
  SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
AS
INSERT INTO emp(empid, time_added) VALUES(100,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
+-------------------------------+
| status                        |
|-------------------------------|
| Task T1 successfully created. |
+------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

building it up:

```
SELECT CURRENT_WAREHOUSE();
```

gives:

| CURRENT_WAREHOUSE() |
| --- |
| COMPUTE_WH |

```
BEGIN
    let task_sql text := 'SELECT 1';
    let sql text := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task_name warehouse = ' || CURRENT_WAREHOUSE() || ' schedule = ''1 minute'' AS ' || task_sql;

    return sql;
END;
```

gives:

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task_name warehouse = COMPUTE_WH schedule = '1 minute' AS SELECT 1 |

which if we test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task_name warehouse = COMPUTE_WH schedule = '1 minute' AS SELECT 1;
```

works just fine.

| status |
| --- |
| Task TASK_NAME successfully created. |

thus:

```
BEGIN
    let task_sql text := 'SELECT 1';
    let sql text := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task_name warehouse = ' || CURRENT_WAREHOUSE() || ' schedule = ''1 minute'' AS ' || task_sql;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql;
    return sql;
END;
```

also works just fine:

```
describe task task_name;
```

| created_on | name | id | database_name | schema_name | owner | comment | warehouse | schedule | predecessors | state | definition | condition | allow_overlapping_execution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-04 17:06:17.858 -0700 | TASK_NAME | 01a36466-6310-6f1f-0000-000000000002 | TEST | TEST | ACCOUNTADMIN |  | COMPUTE_WH | 1 minute |  | suspended | SELECT 1 |  | false |

Answer (score 0):

If you want the task to choose an active warehouse for every run, I'm afraid it is not possible (would be a lovely feature though).

But if you want to use a warehouse that is active at the moment of creation, which doesn't make much sense to me, then I'd go with something like this:

```
show warehouses;
set wh = (select top 1 "name" from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where "state" = 'STARTED');

CREATE TASK task_name
  warehouse = $wh
  SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
AS
    select 1;
```